# how send parameter value with & character for GET or POST

Tags: php

Can someone help me to display the data ? My problem is when the data has a symbol of `&` From `$_GET` to get a data on a `href` it is not displayed. when data does not have a symbol of `&` it is displayed.

When Title has a `&` symbol the data won't display.

```
<a href="Reserved.php?Details=<?php echo $Reserve['Title']; ?>"><button name="Details" type="button" value="Details"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Details</button></a>
<?Php
if(isset($_GET['Details'])){
                $Details = $_REQUEST['Details'];


                    $Reserve_Query = mysql_query("SELECT a.*, b.*, c.*, d.*, e.*, f.* FROM tblReserved a, tblUser b, tblResources c, tblAuthor d, tblCategory e, tblResourcesType f WHERE a.User_ID = b.User_ID AND a.Accession_No = c.Accession_No AND c.Accession_No = d.Accession_No AND c.Category_ID = e.Category_ID AND c.Type_ID = f.Type_ID AND c.Title = '$Details'");
                    $Reserve = mysql_fetch_array($Reserve_Query);
                ?>
                <tr align="center" style="border: 1px solid #115a01;">
                    <td><?php echo $Reserve['Title']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $Reserve['Author']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $Reserve['Category']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $Reserve['Resources_Type']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td colspan="4" height="5"></td></tr>
}
```

Comment: We cannot help with such a vague description. You need to add your code to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Very lame question. At least provide the code to analyse.

Comment: ok sir i will edit it

Comment: `urlencode()` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: You should read up on sql injection.

Comment: @jeroen - do you have idea sir ?

Comment: Yes, you should read up on sql injection.

Comment: ok sir i will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this function "urlencode"

```
//if variable :jeans&shirts   
 echo $variable = urlencode($_GET['variable']);
//out put will be jeans%26shirts
```

your code will be

```
  <a href="Reserved.php?Details=<?php echo urlencode($Reserve['Title']); ?>"><button name="Details" type="button" value="Details"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Details</button></a>
```

//your Reserved.php for getting value

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_GET['Details'])){
                   echo  $Details = urldecode($_REQUEST['Details']);
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: urldecode is just for explaining it will be helpful to any other viewer those will use urlencode and urldecode for same page

Comment: thank you so much sir for helping me :) now i also understand whats use of urlencode and urldecode